# computing the length of codewords in Shannon-Fano-Elias

Tags: information-theory

I have this message:

```
I should write a letter.
```

I want to code this message using Shannon-Fano-Elias method. First I should find the probability of each letter and then find its codeword. I'm confused about computing the Li (which shows the length of each codeword). which one of these Formulas should be used in order to find the Li:

Li = ceiling function of log(1/Pi)

or

Li = (ceiling function of log(1/Pi)) + 1

Comment: It's the latter. See algorithm description and references [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon–Fano–Elias_coding).

Comment: I saw several examples. In some of them the length was computed using the first formula and in some of them, the second formula was used. So I wanted to ask whether there is a difference or not

Comment: Hmm. Could post the sources, so someone can take a look at the discrepancy?
It's been a while since I've looked at this stuff, so take the rest with a pinch of salt, but, in essence, the $1 = \log 2$ comes from picking the codeword to be the shortest binary number $b \in (\sum_{j< i} P_j , \sum_{j\le i} P_j)$ s.t. changing the least significant bit does not push $b$ out of the interval. In principle you could do a $d$-ary Shannon-Fano Elias code, in which case the overhead would only be $\log (1 + 1/d)$, but this should be explicitly stated.

Comment: Just, btw, the length $\lceil -\log p_i \rceil$ is used in Huffman codes, maybe that was the example  being worked out?

Comment: We solved several problems in the class, some of them with the first formula and two of them with the second. This is what has made me confused. So, according to you and the source you mentioned, in Shannon-Fano-Elias, the length of each codeword is computed using   ⌈log⁡(1/pi)⌉ +1 ?

Comment: Aye, and the same is mentioned in Cover & Thomas, so I'll be willing to accept it as gospel. Of course, the best bet would be to confirm with your instructor. Also, because I didn't mention it before, the reason you don't want a change in the least significant bit to push you out of the interval is so that you get a prefix code. You might want to try to prove this, it's a fun little exercise.